# Can't able to access the template folder from frontend container. (flask) ( docker-compose.yml )

Tags: python, html, docker, flask, docker-compose

i am trying to connect & build **two docker file** with **docker-compose**. I am new to docker & then its getting confused while connecting with docker-compose. Main purpose: connecting frontend & backend (of flask application) via **docker-compose**

> **If my Dockerfile & docker-compose.yml file wrong. please correct me**

- like front end in one frontend folder with Dockerfile.
- back end in another folder with Dockerfile. (connecting this 2, via
  doc-comp)

**Here is my file structure**
[Here is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Grq.png)

**Here is my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
       build: ./frontend
       ports:
         - 5000:80      
       volumes:
        - .:/usr/share/nginx/htm
        
  backend:
      build: ./backend
      depends_on:
         - frontend
      ports:
         - 5001:80      
      volumes:
         - /home/doc-tryy-2/frontend:/usr/src/app    

volumes:
  asset-volume4:
     driver: local
```

**Here is my frontend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/htm
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/htm
EXPOSE 5000
```

**Here is my backend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

**Here is my backend/app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'hello'

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        uname = request.form["uname"]
        return render_template("loginpage.html", uname=uname)
    else:
        return render_template("loginpage.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=80,host='0.0.0.0')
```

**Here is my templates/loginepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Logg</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="John"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<h1>hi {{uname}}</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?  Is there any specific output or error message you're getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze at the port 5001 it is showing `Couldn't connect to a server on port 5001` & in port 5000 it is showing `welcom to nginx`(i.e) nginx welcom page

Comment: @DavidMaze i thing, both docker & docker-compose file are slightly wrong. Bro can u pl correct me.

Comment: The two things that stand out are using an old version of the Compose file format (`3` is `3.0`, I'd recommend `3.8` or `3.9`) and overwriting your image's code with `volumes:` mounts (I'd recommend just deleting them).  The Nginx image `EXPOSE` line is wrong (and unnecessary; the base image already `EXPOSE 80`), and you're copying your static files into the wrong directory (use `/usr/share/nginx/html`, with an `l` on the end).  You will need custom configuration to reverse proxy to the backend container as well.